# Laplace Transform of an Piecewise Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Write

$f(t) = \begin{cases}
5,& \mbox{if} \quad 0 \leq t \lt 3 \\
-4,& \mbox{if} \quad 3 \leq t \lt 7 \\
0,& \mbox{if} \quad t \geq 7   
\end{cases}$

as a unit step function and find the Laplace transform.

Workings:

The unit step function is

$f(t) = 5 + u(t-3)(-9) + u(t-7)(4)$

$f(t) = 5 - 9u(t-3) + 4u(t-7)$

The Laplace transform would then be:

$\mathcal L \{f(t)\} = \mathcal L \{5\} - 9 \mathcal L \{u(t-3)\} + 4 \mathcal L \{u(t-4)\}$

$\mathcal L \{f(t)\} = \frac{5}{s} - \frac{9e^{-3s}}{s} - \frac{e^{-4s}}{s}$

I'm not sure if this is correct. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have a sign error in one place, and technically the $5$ should be $5u(t-0)$, but you are otherwise in good shape.

Comment: For the $5$ I was going by my notes where my professor never writes the $u(t-0)$. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You do still have the sign error: in the last term of your Laplace transform you should have $+$, not $-$.

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have, $f(t)=5u(t-0)-9u(t-3)+4u(t-7)$, so

$\displaystyle\mathcal L\{f(t)\}=5\cdot\frac{1}{s}-9\cdot\frac{e^{-3s}}{s}+4\cdot\frac{e^{-7s}}{s}=\frac{5}{s}-\frac{9}{s}e^{-3s}+\frac{4}{s}e^{-7s}.$